# How to read response from serveur with angularjs and $resource

Tags: json, angularjs, resources

I try to read Json from local server, and nothing appear.
 I tried many different ways, but still cannot access the data in the object. You can see the code below:

Angular.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

function ControllerMsg($scope, $resource) {
  var Msgs = $resource(url, null, {
      getAll: {method: 'JSON', isArray: false}
    });

  $scope.messages = Msgs.getAll();

}
```

Index.html

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(data, msgData) in messages">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in msgData">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{msgData}}</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In response firebug tab, I see :

```
{"Message":[{"id":"0","key":"key 1","value":"Value 1"},{"id":"1","key":"key 2","value":"Value 2"}]}
```

Any help or suggestions to solve this problem is greatly appreciate!

Finally i find an error with Chrome : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ...

Any help ?

Comment: Could be wrong but you may need to call `$scope.apply()`

Comment: thanks, but nothing appears

Answer (score 0):

You messages seems to be an array, so the repeat should be like

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in message">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{message}}</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i find the solution, the wrong thing, with local server, we can't use this kind of url:

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/blabla
```

only this

```
/mywebapp/blabla
```

because [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)